# debugging with eclipse not showing breakpoints

Tags: java, android, eclipse, debugging, osx-mountain-lion

I am debugging an android project. I set a number of breakpoints. Then I go to DDMS (or click debug or debug as). The code is stopping but not in the source. Apparently it is stopping in the byte code of `.class` files. Basically, the name of the file where it is supposed to break would show up, with a red text "source not found". Does anyone know how to fix this? Yesterday it was on and off: when it comes on like that I would restart eclipse and if I am luck it would work otherwise I would have to restart again. Does anyone know a good stable fix for this?

Note that I am using GEP for app-engine connected android project. So I have Java 7 installed for app engine and Java 6 for android. Still, this problem is relatively new. Yesterday it was on and off. Today, no luck at all.

Comment: You may need to have the same JDK versions for both GEP and Android i.e. Java 6. Note: Java 7 is not yet supported in Android.

Comment: Java 7 is required for app engine, and java 6 is required for android. so I must use both. But again the problem is tenacious only today. Yesterday it was intermittent. And before that everything was fine. I don't know what changed. But I was hoping someone else had experienced this or knows the fix.

Comment: Hate to point out the obvious, but you are using the JDK and not JRE, right? Incidentally, is GEP a typo for GAE, or is it Gene Expression Programming you're referring to?

Comment: GEP is Google Eclipse Plugin.

Comment: Maybe this [link](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-projects-cmdline.html#debuggingPort) might help.